# Values in symbology tab of layer properties not showing up

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, visualisation

I am trying to colorize (quantify) a chloropleth map based on rent price data in ArcMap 10.2.1. The rent price value is from my .xlsx excel table, which is joined with my shapefile. However, the rent price value is missing from the drop-down list of values under the symbology tab. I know that the data was joined without any errors, so I'm not sure why I'm not able to color-code my map based on the rent price data.

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing?

EDIT: The rent price was listed as a string value and so I added a new numeric field to the attribute table of the census tract shapefile (shown below), but I'm not sure how to get the values from the string column into the numeric column.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to colourise based on quantity or category? What is the field type of the rent price? Numeric or text?

Comment: This is not a question seeking data so please do not restore the [tag:data] tag to it.

Comment: Arcgis thinks this is text,not numeric

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks, you were correct. I checked field properties and the rent price column was in-fact listed as a string value. So I added a new numeric (double) field and named it, but I'm not sure how to get the values from the string column into the numeric column.

Comment: Normally you use field calculator for this. To be sure please update you question with screenshot of table in arcgis

Comment: @FelixIP I inserted the attribute table above. How do I use field calculator to transfer the values into the new column?

Comment: Use icons to select rows "gross"<>'-'. Right click on new field-field calculator

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field in your shapefile of type 'Double' or 'Float'.

Right  click on the new field.

Select 'calculate field'.

In the field calculator, enter "MedianGrossRent" and hit ok.

This will calculate the MedianGrossRent values into the new field as numbers.